# How does python csv module understand end of line vs. newline

Tags: python, csv, file-io, newline

This is more of a request for explanation of how the csv module really understands data coming in from a file. I don't quite understand a quirk I've come across a few times tied specifically to new line characters.

With the following code:

```
with open(filename, 'rbU') as inCsvFile:
    for row in csv.reader(inCsvFile):
        print repr(row)
```

I get the following lines printed

```
['ID', 'AFTADM', 'AFTORD', 'AFTREM', 'AFTOTH', 'AFTOTX', 'COMM']
['3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', 'New, had to look up']
['3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', 'Percieved  complexity']
['3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', 'Stress per se']
['3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', 'no records']
['10', '2', '1', '2', '2', '', 'Please ignore the crossouts!\nMix-up, very late start\nCould not get database to work -- unable to view  data']
['10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['10', '1', '1', '2', '2', '', '']
['10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['11', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'viewed  results', '']
['11', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['11', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['11', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['11', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['11', '2', '2', '2', '2', '', '']
['12', '2', '1', '2', '2', '', '']
['12', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['12', '2', '2', '2', '1', 'emailed', '']
...
```

Specifically the row I'm interested in is:

```
['10', '2', '1', '2', '2', '', 'Please ignore the crossouts!\nMix-up, very late start\nCould not get database to work -- unable to view  data']
```

If I try to handle this without the csv module using code such as:

```
with open(filename, 'rbU') as inFile:
    for row in inFile:
        print repr(row)
```

This treats it as a text stream and I wind up with that one row turning into three:

```
'10,2,1,2,2,,"Please ignore the crossouts!\n'
'Mix-up, very late start\n'
'Could not get database to work -- unable to view  data"\n'
```

I know it's the newline characters doing it, but how does the csv module understand end of row and not get tripped up by the newline characters?

Is there specific code I could use (without reinventing the csv module) that would allow me to deal with this sort of scenario without using the `csv.reader`?

Contents of file for anyone who wants to see the data file I'm discussing:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19141650/test.csv

Comment: Use the Source Luke :-) `import csv; print csv.__file__` and open it in your favorite editor

Comment: @FredrikPihl: you'll have to look at the C module instead.

Comment: @stoves Please open the CSV file in a text editor and have a look at that famous line. Now, what looks like the line in the CSV file? it is a string with embedded _representations_ of newlines ('\n') or are there _real_ ASCII characters 0X0A and you see, in the text editor, the logical record split over a number of physical lines?

Comment: @gboffi: they are real, because the produced Python lists are containing actual newlines. They'd be escaped otherwise, to `'\\n'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, got it (after a while :-). Thanks

Comment: @gboffi I expanded the details of my question and added a link to a file for example explanation. They are newlines, and opening the file in a text editor puts them on separate rows as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column is **quoted**. There column starts with a `"` and ends with another. Everything between those two quotes is recognized as a column:

```
"Please ignore the crossouts!\n
Mix-up, very late start\n
Could not get database to work -- unable to view  data"
```

When writing CSV files, the module will also use quoting where needed, unless you tell it to do otherwise with the [`quoting` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting); you can set it to any of the [`csv.QUOTE_ALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL), [`csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL), [`csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) or [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) constants:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
>>> writer.writerow([5, 'spam', 'foo\nbar'])
"5","spam","foo
bar"
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>>> writer.writerow([5, 'spam', 'foo\nbar'])
5,spam,"foo
bar"
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
>>> writer.writerow([5, 'spam', 'foo\nbar'])
5,"spam","foo
bar"
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
>>> writer.writerow([5, 'spam', 'foo\nbar'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

Note how the module actually issues an error when disabling quoting and trying to write a value with a newline.

The same constants apply when reading; the default is taken from the dialect chosen, and the default Excel dialect has `quoting` set to `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

Comment: You were right about newline characters, a line in a file like `blah\nfoo` would have been shown as "blah\\n" by python, note the extra slash.  Thank you, I love learning just a little more than I hate being wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module interprets everything between quote marks `"` as part of the string, even newlines.